# Waiting your comments how to use with verb on below sentence

Tags: american-english, exam-questions

> Q.  I ____  john and Liz after school tomorrow.
>
> - A. am meet
> - B. am meeting
> - C. met
>
> Q2. My sister ____ john and Liz after school tomorrow.
>
> - A. Is meet
> - B. Is meeting
> - C. met

Herewith I attached 2 questions from one Korean student's exam.
Actually these were very weird in case of mine also can't choose anyone of them.

Why there isn't **D. (will meet)** as I thought.

I'm waiting your brilliant comments about the above sentences.

Answer (score 0):

For Q1, variants A and C are definitely a no-go.

For Q2, variants A and C are definitely a no-go also.

So we see that both variants B remain, and they are both present continuous. Fortunately, [in English, present continuous can be used to express future](https://www.ef.com/wwen/english-resources/english-grammar/present-continuous-future-arrangements/):

> - I'**m meeting** Jim at the airport = Jim and I have discussed this.
> - I **am leaving** tomorrow. = I've already bought my train ticket.
> - We'**re having** a staff meeting next Monday = all members of staff have been told about it.